# Swift 3 - Core Data - Fetched Results Controller Access Relationship Attribute

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, entity, fetch

The issue being faced is my inability to access an entity's attributes when it is a relationship to the entity I am fetching.

In relation to my app, I am creating a fitness tracking app, I have a detail table view controller with my tracked activities. When I tap a cell the view segues into another View Controller to display a map of the tracked locations.

Using the fetched results controller I am fetching "Entity1". When I tap a cell 'I think' I want to segue & pass "Entity2" attribute values into another view controller. Except the relationship from "Entity1" to "Entity2" is a "To Many" relationship and in the core data properties for "Entity1",

```
extension Entity1 
{
    // instead of "Entity2" being represented as
    // @NSManaged var entity2: Entity2?

    //it is represented as 
    @NSManaged var entity2: NSOrderedSet?
}
```

thus i can not access "Entity2" properties.

How I fetch "Entity1":

```
func fetchEntity1ResultsController( _ context: NSManagedObjectContext )
{
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Entity1> = NSFetchRequest( entityName: "Entity1" )
    request.sortDescriptors  = [ NSSortDescriptor( key: "timestamp", ascending: false ) ]

    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController( fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil )
    fetchedResultsController?.delegate = self

    do
    {
        try fetchedResultsController?.performFetch()
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Couldn't fetch results controller")
    }
}
```

How I would attempt to access "Entity2" properties.

```
private func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
{
    guard let entity1 = fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) else { return }

    entity1.entity2.//No core data properties listed here
}
```

To conclude: My question is - How can I tap a cell that is the "Entity1" description where "Entity2" is in relationship to and access "Entity2" attribute values to display that data in my map view controller.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a to-many relationship, what you're calling `entity2` is a set of multiple instances of `Entity2`. That's what the "many" part of "to-many" means here-- one `Entity1` is related to a collection of multiple `Entity2` instances. You can't access `Entity2` attributes on a set, because it's a collection of more than one instance. To access `Entity2` attributes you first need to select one object from the set.

How you do that depends on how your app is supposed to work. You have an `NSOrderedSet`, and it has a variety of options for selecting one of the objects it contains. You could ask for the first object, or the last one, or the `Entity2` at a specific location in the ordered set. There are other options besides these; see the `NSOrderedSet` documentation for more info on them.

Comment: Excellent - took a little thinking a was able to figure out how to approach accessing the properties. Typecasting was the solution when accessing an array - let entity2 = entity1.entity2 as! Entity2. then went from there :)

Comment: Since `entity2` is declared as an `NSMutableSet` in your code snippet, I'm surprised that typecasting to `Entity2` even compiles, much less works.

Comment: my apologies - I forgot to access the actual property. In that comment it should have been 'let entity2 = entity1.entity2.firstObject as! Entity2'